# Tomcat 9 webapp does not start

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tomcat

I am working on a webapp with a Tomcat and want to deploy it on the production server, windows server 2012R2.
My application works just fine on a local tomcat web server (also 9) but when I try to deploy it on prod in a tomcat web server, it doesn't work. I see it on the manager page, but I get a 404 error when I try to access it.
I see the logs saying the war was correctly deployed but that is the end of it.

Why does it work on local but not on prod when i use the same tools (installer even) on both sides?

Edit:

logs catalina

```
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nom version serveur :   Apache Tomcat/9.0.37
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Serveur compilé :       Jun 30 2020 20:09:49 UTC
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version du serveur :    9.0.37.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nom de l'OS :           Windows Server 2012 R2
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version OS :            6.3
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture :          amd64
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home :             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version JVM :           1.8.0_191-b12
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Fournisseur de la JVM : Oracle Corporation
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE :         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME :         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : exit
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : abort
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Xms128m
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Xmx256m
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La librairie Apache Tomcat Native basée sur APR qui permet des performances optimales dans les environnements de production n'a pas été trouvée sur le java.library.path : [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\shared\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\idrac;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Arcserve\Unified Data Protection\Management\BIN;.]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.345 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.392 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load L'initialisation du serveur a pris [437] millisecondes
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.423 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service [Catalina]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.423 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Démarrage du moteur de Servlets : [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.439 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\tracoeuf.war] de l'application web
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.219 INFOS [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Au moins un fichier JAR a été analysé pour trouver des TLDs mais il n'en contenait pas, le mode "debug" du journal peut être activé pour obtenir une liste complète de JAR scannés sans succès ; éviter d'analyser des JARs inutilement peut améliorer sensiblement le temps de démarrage et le temps de compilation des JSPs
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.344 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Le déploiement de l'archive de l'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\tracoeuf.war] s'est terminé en [13 890] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.344 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.360 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] de l'application web s'est terminé en [16] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.360 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.391 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [31] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.391 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] de l'application web s'est terminé en [31] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Le démarrage du serveur a pris [14027] millisecondes
```

logs localhost

```
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nom version serveur :   Apache Tomcat/9.0.37
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Serveur compilé :       Jun 30 2020 20:09:49 UTC
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version du serveur :    9.0.37.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nom de l'OS :           Windows Server 2012 R2
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version OS :            6.3
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture :          amd64
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home :             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Version JVM :           1.8.0_191-b12
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Fournisseur de la JVM : Oracle Corporation
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE :         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME :         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : exit
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : abort
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Xms128m
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Argument de la ligne de commande : -Xmx256m
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.095 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent La librairie Apache Tomcat Native basée sur APR qui permet des performances optimales dans les environnements de production n'a pas été trouvée sur le java.library.path : [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\shared\bin;C:\Program Files\Dell\SysMgt\idrac;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Arcserve\Unified Data Protection\Management\BIN;.]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.345 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.392 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load L'initialisation du serveur a pris [437] millisecondes
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.423 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service [Catalina]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.423 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Démarrage du moteur de Servlets : [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:37.439 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\tracoeuf.war] de l'application web
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.219 INFOS [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars Au moins un fichier JAR a été analysé pour trouver des TLDs mais il n'en contenait pas, le mode "debug" du journal peut être activé pour obtenir une liste complète de JAR scannés sans succès ; éviter d'analyser des JARs inutilement peut améliorer sensiblement le temps de démarrage et le temps de compilation des JSPs
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.313 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.344 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Le déploiement de l'archive de l'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\tracoeuf.war] s'est terminé en [13 890] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.344 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.360 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] de l'application web s'est terminé en [16] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.360 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.391 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] de l'application web s'est terminé en [31] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.391 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire d'application web [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Le déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] de l'application web s'est terminé en [31] ms
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Démarrage du gestionnaire de protocole ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Sep-2020 16:55:51.422 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Le démarrage du serveur a pris [14027] millisecondes
```

Comment: Please don't cross post the same question on multiple sites. Pick one and delete your other question. It would be helpful if your logs would be in english though ... they should be when you specify the environment variable `LANG=C` for your service.

Comment: Which sites do you think would be the most able tom help me here? stack overflow for the development side or server fault for the server side?
Also, how do I change the language for the logs? I didn't find this variable

Comment: IMO this site is a better fit.

Comment: Try setting `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` `"%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"` to change the log language. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827948/how-can-change-default-locale-for-tomcat-in-windows

Comment: I tried adding `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US` in `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat` according to https://knowm.org/set-tomcats-default-locale/ but it didn't change anything to the logs

Comment: That's odd. Maybe its a different setting for Tomcat 9. Anyway I would check what the Tomcat logs when you make a request to the webapp and get a 404.

Comment: In fact, that's what I did for the logs I posted. I deleted the log dir, relaunched tomcat and then tried to access my app. I guess there was no error because it was a version issue ?
Also, I'm pretty sure i did not do it right for the settings, but I don't know how or why. Still, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

As always, the issue is with the chair-keyboard interface...
So it appears that my project is based on java 13 and that my tomcat server was operating with java 8.

I reinstalled my server, put the correct jdk (instead of the previous jre) and now it's working. Now I only have to see why I can't access it from the network.

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: Great that you managed to solve it. Don't forget to accept your answer, so it gets marked as "solved" in the system.

Comment: I would love to, but as a new user, I have to wait 2 days before I can. I will do as soon as possible!